# Do runtime-loaded assets consume memory/resources if they're not being used? More than compiled assets?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, browser, actionscript

I'm making a game for the browser that has a lot of assets, but not all of them are needed at once. I'm deciding whether to embed my assets at compile time or load them at run time. **I'm not concerned about loading time -- only the performance of the game during run-time.**

1. If I load these assets and store them into memory for eventual use later in the game, will they consume system resources just being latent in an AssetLoader? Will that affect performance?
2. If I embed these assets, will they consume system resources just being latent in the compiled SWF?
3. Is there a difference in performance between these 2 methods?

Comment: As with many performance issues; it often comes down to "it depends" and I suspect you'll have to test to see what works for you.  Embedding assets will increase the initial download size of the SWF; hands down.  Whether it is big enough to matter depends on what the assets are.

Comment: Do you mean that only "big enough" assets will affect run-time performance?

Comment: That last sentence was unclear.  I wouldn't expect the size of the download to have any affect on run time performance; unless the size of the download is larger than the available memory.  If you only care about run-time performance, I would assume that loading up all assets at the start would give you better performance than loading assets as needed. But, you'll have to test to see what happens. I do not believe a concrete "yes or no" answer exists to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. They will consume RAM, but not CPU cycles. In-game performance is only affected when all RAM is used and the program needs to use virtual memory on the hard disk.
2. Embedded assets sit in RAM, just like the runtime-loaded assets described above. However, they likely will use less RAM because their file size will probably see a decrease when being compiled to SWF bytecode during compilation.
3. The only performance hit on the CPU is taken from the loading and instantiation processes.

   - While loading assets at runtime, a `Loader` object used to acquire assets will use CPU cycles as it gathers external data. Compiled assets are already loaded, so they win that battle.
   - During construction, compiled assets are created using a slightly different process than runtime-loaded assets. They take a different amount of time to construct. I'm not sure about how these processes differ, but I imagine it's fairly negligible. If being loaded more than once, I believe runtime-loaded assets are acquired from the system's cache, whereas compiled assets exist within the SWF. Runtime-loaded assets can also be symbols within a SWF that are exported for runtime sharing as part of a runtime shared library.

Comment: Since you're answering your own question; is this answer based on research or experimentation or.. ??

Comment: I'm regurgitating the information posted in this thread (including deleted responses to my question) though my own interpretation and knowledge of how memory is used. Please edit anything that is wrong or misleading.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, maybe (depending on RAM available, on a modern machine not
   running 3D studio max I wouldn't think it would be a major concern,
   memory is cheap).
2. Yes in terms of memory, see above in terms of
   performance.
3. It depends, but in an example I tried with everything
   local Embed vs load at run-time difference was negligible, I think
   I'm going to go with run-time loading because I want to load sets of
   images to do flip-book style animation.

See example here (source view enabled, linked below apparently "pure AS3" projects don't setup the right click menu correctly when checking the box for source view in release build):

http://www.shaunhusain.com/DrawTextRandomly/

http://www.shaunhusain.com/DrawTextRandomly/srcview/

Some things to be aware of on the example above, each image is ~1.5Kb it loads 90 images for the explosion animation.  Using 1 loader over and over it took about 4 seconds to run **locally** I upped it to using 90 Loaders so they all happen concurrently and that got it down to 500ms which is in my opinion reasonable.  Embedding would require that I write out the Embeds for every single image (I used a trace in the loop to accomplish this to test it out, but the run-time performance of using the images was nil, which I suppose should have been expected), like you I'm not too concerned with having a loading bar for a couple of seconds during startup but don't want to have to keep adding Embeds as it just makes the code a mess so I'm going with run-time loading (at least for now).